# import files to database

Tags: java

i have a method in java that opens an excel file and copies it into a database. This works fine.

What i want to do is write a java service that looks for new files in a folder and then calls my method as outlined above renames the file to Done-originalfilename.xls.
Then the service loops constantly looking for files that are not named with Done-*

How do i write a service in java to do this. i am coming from a Microsoft background where i would just write a windows service. What is the equivalent in java and any example to create a service that loops based on a timer to look for new files would be brilliant.

thanks

Comment: I guess you are looking for a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: ok - and what about actually writing a windows service - how is that done or example would be great

Comment: Well, I have no idea of window services. And I didn't work with the ScheduledExecutorServices, so I can't provide you with an example. But I guess google will lead to some examples. Sorry 'bout that :)